# c# Disable ScrollWheel on Trackbar

Tags: c#, winforms, events, trackbar

How can I disable the valuechange with mouse wheel on trackbars?
When scrolling down on the interface users can change trackbar values by mistake
I'm using Windows forms c#.
I couldn't find no property to stop this event..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue with this:
With normal event declaration..

```
Control = new TrackBar();
Control.MouseWheel += Control_MouseWheel;
private void Control_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true;
}
```

Using anonymous method

```
var Control = new TrackBar();
Control.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true;
});
```

What it does is to prevent further execution..

Edit:
Using Labda expression as said by Sriram Sakthivel

```
Control.MouseWheel += (sender, e) =>((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true;
```

Comment: What you have isn't a lambda expression. It is an anonymous method. With lambda it becomes much shorter. `Control.MouseWheel += (sender, e) =>((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true;`